# Grails - Where to store properties related to domains

Tags: arrays, grails

This is something I have been struggling about for some time now. The thing is: I have many (20 or so) *static* arrays of values. I say *static* because that is how I'm actually storing them, as static arrays inside some domains. For example, if I have a list of known websites, I do:

```
class Website {
   ...
   static websites = ["web1", "web2" ...]
}
```

But I do this just while developing, because I can easily change the arrays if needed, but what I'm going to do when the application is ready for deployment? In my project it is very probable that, at some point, these arrays of values change. I've been researching on that matter, one can store application properties inside an external .properties file, but it will be impossible to store an array, even futile, because if some array gets an additional value, the application can't recognize it until the name of the new property is added where needed.
Another approach is to store this information in the database, but for some reason it seems like a waste to add 20 or more tables that will have just two rows, an id and a name.
And the last option, as far as I know, would be an XML, but I'm not very experienced with those. It seems groovy has a way of creating and reading XML files relatively easy, but I don't know how difficult would be to modify an XML whose layout is predefined in the application.

Needless to say that storing them in the config.groovy is not an option since any change will require to recompile.

I haven't come across some "standard" (maybe a best practice?) way of dealing with these.

So the questions is: Where to store these arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Enum` for a fixed set of attributes. Do this, if you rely at some places in your code on some concrete values.
2. If you do not rely on the attributes within your code (which you obviously don't), use a `String`-type. In this case, if you need to provide a select box, just do a `distinct`-query on this property in your database.
3. Default: Use a domain class per dynamic set of attributes. Another table is OK.

Comment: So there would be a lot of one-to-one relationships. And I need to filter and sort depending on some of those attributes. Is it really faster to sort, for example, Book.category.nameOfCategory (attribute in a separate table) than Book.nameOfCategory (attribute stored directly in the table ).

Comment: It's not one-to-one if multiple instances have the same category. If it is performance, which scares you, have a look at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormComposition.

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple as arrays you should use groovy own type of property files. They allow you too define properties as proper groovy variables (not just strings) and obviously loading them would be done dinamically in a simple way by using ConfigSlurper. For an example on how to use this kind of file you can have a look at the following [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper):

For defining properties:

```
 my.property.array=[1,2,3,4]
```

For loading property files:

```
 def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('myconfig.groovy').toURL())
 assert [1,2,3,4] == config.my.property.array
```

Tip: When you want to access the property files you want to do it in a way that can work for any environment. To make paths environment-independent use the following path as the root path:

```
 import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder 

 def ctx = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.servletContext 
 def rootPath = ctx.contextPath
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach, but for some reason, for me it seems like ConfigSlurper is to store app configuration instead of "external data" (something that the user can see and modify).

Comment: Yep, agreed that is not the envisioned use but it works no? :P